# Rails 3 Engine - Provide Config For Users

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, configuration, rails-engines

I can't seem to find any documentation on how to do the following: I need to provide a config variable for any applications using my engine so that they can easily pass settings to my engine.

Does anyone have any links to a proper or accepted way to do this?

**EDIT:** As an update, I figured out a decent way to do this. Code is below.

```
# file: lib/my_engine.rb
module MyEngine

  class Engine < Rails::Engine

    initializer "my_engine.configure_rails_initialization" do |app|
      # Engine configures Rails app here, this is not what my question was about
    end

  end

  # This is what I was trying to figure out
  def self.config(&block)
    @@config ||= MyEngine::Configuration.new

    yield @@config if block

    return @@config
  end

end
```

This allows any application using my engine to configure it like below in any of their initializers or their environment.rb file, calling any methods defined in the `MyEngine::Configuration` class:

```
MyEngine.config do |config|
  config.some_configuration_option = "Whatever"
end
```

Comment: Nice solution! However, when I tried it, I had to use this syntax : @@config ||= MyEngine::Engine::Configuration.new

Comment: In general, it's better to use a class instance variable (only one `@`). Since `self` is the class at this point, you'll still get the behavior you want (that is, it will still be a property of the class), but you'll avoid some strangenesses that class variables have in Ruby.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer:

Create a file called your_engine_class.rb and put in config/initializers of your hosting app. Here is an example of this file.

```
module YourEngineClass
  class Engine < Rails::Engine
    config.param_name = 'value'    
  end
end
```

Then inside your main engine.rb you can access:

```
config.param_name
```

Longer answer: I created a stub engine that includes this and lots of other standard configuration you'll need, you can use it as a starting point:

http://keithschacht.com/creating-a-rails-3-engine-plugin-gem/

Comment: Thanks for your example. It's not quite what I was looking for, but your code was valuable nonetheless.

Comment: So you have to explicitly somehow inform every user of you engine to create such a file and put it in his app's `config/initializers` directory. It is inconvinient.

Answer (score 5):

I personally like the pattern [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) uses, which defines a class method in your engine's module and then an initializer in the parent application.

#### Create a class method to call from the parent application

```
module YourEngine
  class << self
    attr_accessor :your_config_var
  end

  def self.setup(&block)
    # You can yield your own object encapsulating your configuration logic/state
    yield self
  end
end
```

#### Call the class method in an initializer in the parent application

```
YourEngine.setup do |config|
  config.your_config_var = "nyan cat"
end
```

Now you are free to access `your_config_var` in your engine's initialization process. You can create a file in your engine's `config/initializers` directory or use the [Rails Initializer](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#initializers) hooks.

I like this approach since you have more control on what configuration object you expose to clients and aren't overriding the engine's `config` method.

Answer (score 4):

Seems better to me as follow :

```
#lib/my_engine.rb
require 'rails'

module MyEngine
  class Engine < Rails::Engine

  end

  def self.config(&block)
    yield Engine.config if block
    Engine.config
  end
end
```

Comment: Perhaps I am not following your code very well, but wouldn't the `config` method return itself (i.e. the method, not a configuration object)?

Comment: Engine.config is the instance of Rails::Engine::Configuration that the engine class allready instanciate (you can read but also add custom keys there as needed)... In your code you instanciate 2 different config instances (one for the engine class, one for the gem/plugin module)